# Prompt to File Message when Reply is Sent Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

I work through approximately 60 email messages a day. Generally, once I reply to an email I have no need for the original email to stay in my inbox. Is there a rule I can setup in Outlook 2013 so that after I reply to an email, I am prompted to file the original email? 
Thanks!
RCF

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you can achive the desired result with Outlook Quick Steps. Just create a Quick Step that does the Reply AND Moves a message into selected folder. There will be no prompt, Outlook will do everything silently.